# Composer doesn't update outdated dependencies

Tags: php, dependencies, composer-php

Well, after running command `composer outdated` I can see there's newer version of phpdocumentor/type-resolver available. Installed version is 0.2.1 and the latest one is 0.3.0. Need to say that it was indirectly installed by component I use and not by me.

Problem is when I run `composer update` or `composer update phpdocumentor/type-resolver`  it says "Nothing to install or update". Why and how to fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might have version constraints blocking the upgrade in your composer.json file.  This is intended to prevent adding in breaking changes.  In your example, the versions are pre-release (0.*), so versioning constraints even act on the miner version.

If you are confident there are no breaking changes or you are prepared to deal with them, edit your composer.json file. Change something like:

```
"phpdocumentor/type-resolver": "0.2.1",
```

to

```
"phpdocumentor/type-resolver": "^0.3",
```

Try `composer upgrade` again and test it out to make sure everything is ok.

Answer (score 13):

probably some dependency have fixed the package release you want to install. Try so the the output of the command to check who are using and at which version the package you listed:

```
composer why-not phpdocumentor/type-resolver 0.3.0
```

NB: in the [current version of the documentation of composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#prohibits) the command is named `prohibits`, so in case this doesn't work try with:

```
composer prohibits phpdocumentor/type-resolver 0.3.0
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have composer 1.4.2 so the first command is OK. Output is: `phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock  3.1.1  requires  phpdocumentor/type-resolver (^0.2.0)`. Is this a problem you're talking about? (Sorry, I started using composer not so long ago).

Comment: Running `composer*update phpdocumentor/type-resolver ^0.3.0` gives nothing. Composer says that "Package 0.3.0 listed for update is not installed. Ignoring." Still need a way to update it to the latest version. Anyone?..