# How do I update a package that's required in composer.json as '^a.b'?

Tags: composer-php

I have a package that's required in my project's composer.json as '^a.b'. Specifically, it's:

```
        "drupal/core-recommended": "^8.8",
```

I don't understand how to get this to update to 8.9.

If I do `composer update drupal/core-recommended`, Composer says:

```
Nothing to install or update
```

If I do `composer require drupal/core-recommended 8.9`, then Composer says there is a requirements problem, because dependencies of this package are locked at versions that are too low for 8.9.

How am I supposed to update it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Composer doesn't update outdated dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44436864/composer-doesnt-update-outdated-dependencies)

Comment: And if there is any message telling you that the update is not possible because of other packages, you should add the `composer.json` and these error messages to your question